# Usage of fuzzy_with_tokens in dateutil parser

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, nlp, python-dateutil

Recently while working in an NLP project I used dateutil parser.
Many have used **fuzzy_with_tokens** while parsing like

```
parse(dtstr, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
```

What is the purpose of fuzzy_with_tokens? What it will do?

Answer (score 0):

From the dateutil.parser [documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

> fuzzy_with_tokens – If True, fuzzy is automatically set to True, and
> the parser will return a tuple where the first element is the parsed
> datetime.datetime datetimestamp and the second element is a tuple
> containing the portions of the string which were ignored: